# Custom Twitter Feed From My Twitter Using Ruby On Rails twitter gem

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, twitter

Okay, I've decided to use the twitter gem.
The problem is I havent a clue how to go about using it because im new to ruby/rails. 
All I require is to display a list of the last 5 tweets from my own twitter account, with the times they were posted. 
I honestly do not know where to begin.

Comment: So why not read the source of those gems *(like the [Twitter](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) gem)* and use it as a guide to create what you're after?

Comment: Also, unless you're doing this strictly for educational purposes, why reinvent the wheel? The gem exists for a reason (to make your life easier).

Comment: this makes complete sense, Ive decided to update my question. The problem is when I mean im a beginner at Ruby, and Ruby on Rails im a complete beginner, so I need a lot of guidance.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a lot out there in the way of tutorials.

The best solution I found (and the one I eventually used) was this javascript solution that bypasses Oauth:

http://jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/#sthash.BYRbZafw.dpbs

I also tried this tutorial's method with the Twitter gem, and got the Oauth working, but the actual tweet display was bad and not easily fixed:

http://www.synaptian.com/blog/posts/using-the-twitter-gem-in-your-rails-application

Finally, you can just make a widget on Twitter using their wizard and embed it in your page with a small piece of code they give you to copy. Here's the link to do it that way.

https://twitter.com/settings/widgets